# php + check if variable value is between two integers

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm new to this, and I think there some issue with my if-else structure, but I cant understand what the problem actually is.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<?php

$num = 1; 

while($num <=10)
{
    if ($num < 4)
    {
    print $num . " is less than 4 /";
    } 
    elseif ($num = 4)
    {
    print $num . " is just 4 /";
    } 
    elseif (($num > 4) && ($num < 10))
    {
    print $num . " is more than 4 and less than 10 /";
    } 
    elseif ($num = 10)
    {
    print $num . " is just 10 /";
    } 

 $num++; 

}
```

?>

I have a couple hours around this so I finally decided to ask.
Any help will be appreciated!  Ty in advance for reading.

Comment: What is the *intended* output?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, you probably want to use the comparison operator `==`

Comment: OMG TY! Im such a noob... i just completly forgot about that. Problem solved now =) Since it has nothing to do withthe topic should i delete it maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using assignment operator '=', use conditional operator

```
<?php

$num = 1; 

    while($num <=10)
    {
        if ($num < 4)
        {
        print $num . " is less than 4 /";
        } 
        elseif ($num == 4)
        {
        print $num . " is just 4 /";
        } 
        elseif (($num > 4) && ($num < 10))
        {
        print $num . " is more than 4 and less than 10 /";
        } 
        elseif ($num == 10)
        {
        print $num . " is just 10 /";
        } 

     $num++; 

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your elseif statements you have to use == instead of =

ex: elseif ($num == 4) instead of elseif ($num = 4)

You might also consider using a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement.
Good luck!

Comment: Yes! my bad. Thanks for the tip onf the switch function. i did not know it and it seems to just the thing to use.

Answer (score 0):

In if condition you need to compare variables. but you are using assignment operator.

Please try this piece of code.

4) && ($num